# How to get Match to return an INT and not an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
    var hashID = location.hash.match(/\d/);
```

Where location.hash eqs:  #/groups/58

I want hashID to equal = 58

Right now it equals an array. How can I get back just 58 as an int?
 THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  var hashID = parseInt(location.hash.match(/\d+/)[0])
```